# Load a .Net WebControl with JQuery and AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, controls

I know this is kind of a conceptual question, but I want to be able to add .Net WebControls to a page based on user input.  I want these controls to be WebControls and UserControls that are generated from the server.  I'm not really sure how to go about doing this while making sure that the controls render fully.  I know I can easily make requests to the server from JQuery, and then add the returned markup to the page with no problem.  Is there any way I can generate the full markup for a WebControl/UserControl to pass back to JQuery through AJAX so I can render it on the page?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using WebForms.

Comment: I'm not super clear on what WebForms applies to, but I am using the System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace.

Comment: I mean ASP.NET WebForms vs ASP.NET MVC. This is trivially easy in MVC.

Comment: Yes, I am using WebForms

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX to make an asynchronous callback to the page. If you want to trigger this from the client, you can probably use `__doPostBack` and override the `RaisePostBackEvent` method in the code-behind.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    loadControls = function(input){
        __doPostBack(input.id, input.value);
    }
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlLoadControls" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server" onkeyup="loadControls(this)" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcLoadedControls" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And then in the code-behind:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(source, eventArgument);
    if (source == txtInput)
    {
        plcLoadedControls.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Hello World!"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to do this with just javascript/jquery and make requests to another page.  I'm wary to have the page go through a full lifecycle every time and I'd rather inject the controls in script.

Comment: If you want to do it with jQuery, you can make an AJAX request and load the content into an `iframe`. To keep it thin and efficient, consider sending the requests to an `HttpHandler` or something.

Comment: iframes are scary because they don't allow scrolling when displayed on an iPad.  Any custom content loaded in one of these controls wouldn't be able to expand beyond the bounds of the container.